# Strange Pycharm editor behavior: creating single character lines after typing f"{

Tags: pycharm

It is hard to explain so let's use a screenshot.  Here I inserted *f"{*  before some existing text - and got this strange editor behavior that some of the subsequent text got placed *one character on a time* on new lines:

[image]

What is going on here?

**Update** This is also happening for *f{'* (single quote not double quote followed by an open brace then arbitrary text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has something to do with `soft wrap`'s  : when I disabled them under `Editor | General | Soft Wraps`  the problem went away.

[image]

Now the bad wraps are gone:

[image]

It appears to be a bug in Pycharm soft wraps.  If anyone knows of a workaround please provide a (better) answer. In the meantime I created a bug for it  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59401

Comment: Note: the scenario causing the bug is not easily reproducible.  Seems infrequent.